# Why does returning EmptyView make AsyncImage not work?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

This code loads the image:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://ychef.files.bbci.co.uk/976x549/p01j3jyb.jpg")) { phase in
    switch phase {
    case .success(let image):
        image
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
    default:
        Text("empty")
    }
}
```

This code does not:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://ychef.files.bbci.co.uk/976x549/p01j3jyb.jpg")) { phase in
    switch phase {
    case .success(let image):
        image
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Why?  The only difference is the default case.

Xcode 13.3.1

Comment: Works fine here. Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

Comment: Oh really?  I'm on 13.3.1...

Comment: Works fine on Xcode 13.3.1 / iOS 15.4 as well.